# How can I reset my advertising identifier in macOS Ventura?

Tags: mac, ventura

How can I reset my advertising identifier in macOS Ventura?

There used to be a button "Reset Advertising Identifier" in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Advertising** but in but it seems to be gone in macOS Ventura.

Comment: Does the advertising identifier still exist? Went away with iOS 14, I think. Not sure when it stopped on macOS.

Comment: I don't see any notes about an Advertising Identifier in the privacy settings descriptions either. You can turn off Personalized Ads if you'd like.